# Помогите найти ошибку в коде Mathlab (Фазовый дальномер)

Tags: matlab, обработка-сигналов

Рассчитываю курсовую. Фазовый дальномер. На вход приёника излучения (ПИ) приходят два гармонических сигнала s1 и s2. s1 - сигнал, отраженный от объекта, имеет фазу fi1. Опорный сигнал - s2 - приходит на ПИ без фазы. 
Необходимо найти получившееся расстояние L1, на теоретическом расстоянии l = 10м, т.е. получить L1 = l = 10м. Т.к. я не вводил шумов и джиттеров.

Так же приложу метод, по которому все рассчитывал.. 
Сам метод работает правильно. Руководитель написал программу в C# и она исправно работает. Мы проверяли код в mathlab - на вид всё верно написано. Поэтому обращаюсь к знатокам :)
спасибо!

```
%Дано:
%запишем скорость света и теоретическое расстояние 
c = 3*10^8; %м/с
l = 10 %м
%частоты с частотного кондиционера
%частоты на ЛД
f1 = 1.95*10^6; %Гц
f2 = 78*10^6; %Гц
%зададим частоту дискретизации
fd = 7.8*10^6; %Гц
%найдём время прохождения импульса до объекта
t0 = 1e1; %колличество периодов
n = 4*t0; %колличество отчётов рассмотрения
h = 1; %шаг разбиения
t = 0:h:t0; %временная сетка
t = t/fd;
fi1 = 4*pi*f1*l/c
% омега
w1 = 2*pi*f1;
%зададим амплитуды
A1 = 1;
A2 = 10;

%% вычисление на f1 = 1.95 МГц
%сигналы на ПИ после ПрОС
s1 = A1*sin(w1*t+fi1);
subplot (4,1,1);
plot (t,s1)
grid;
title ('s1 (t)');

s2 = A2*cos(w1*t);
subplot (4,1,2);
plot (t,s2)
grid;
title ('s2 (t)');

%найдём модуль сигналов s1 и s2
s1mod = abs (s1);
s2mod = abs (s2);

%изменение амплитуды в U раз
U = 1;
s1u = U*s1;
s2u = U*s2;

s1modu = U*s1mod;
s2modu = U*s2mod;

%усреденение
s1s2 = mean(s1u.*s2u);

%усреденение по модулю
s1_ = mean(s1modu);
s2_ = mean(s2modu);

%перемножение усреднёмнных по модулю сигналов
s1s2_ = s1_*s2_;

%найдём фазу
dfi1 = asin(8*s1s2/(pi^2*s1s2_))

%найдём расстояние
L1 = c*dfi1/w1
```

Выводит следующее:

```
l =

    10


fi1 =

    0.8168


dfi1 =

    0.9857


L1 =

   24.1353
```

А должен вывести L1 = l = 10
[image: графики сигналов s1(t) и s2(t)]

[image: дальность до объекта]

[image: вычисление теоретической фазы fi1]

[image: метод вычисления стр1]

[image: метод вычисления стр2]

[image: метод вычисления стр3]

[image: функциональная схема рассчёта]

Comment: Вы смотрели в описание метки [tag:учебное-задание]?

Comment: Смотрел. На что стоит обратить особое внимание?
Я не прошу решить за меня задачу, я прошу помочь найти ошибку в коде.